# Android: Using weak reference of activity/fragment instance instead of strong reference?

Tags: android

In my android application, I have many activities and fragments, and to make the code readable and reusable, I have helper classes for each of the activities and fragments. These helper classes are responsible for everything from populating dynamic views to validations and network related tasks.

Currently, I am passing an instance of the Activity/Fragment to each of the helper classes. My understanding is that each of the helper are instantiated within the activity and will be destroyed along with the activity.

Are there any advantages/disadvantages of passing a weak reference to my helpers instead of a strong reference?

Comment: Are your helper classes internal to the activity/fragment?  If so, they already have an implicit reference.

Comment: @iagreen No they are not internal. I have a hierarchy of Helpers that are used across my application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the lifetime of the helper is within the lifetime of the Activity, then there's no need to use a WeakReference. If the helper can live longer than the Activity, then you should use a WeakReference to avoid retaining the Activity in your object graph when the system destroys it.