# Weak reference instead of getActivity() (Android avoid memory leak)?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, weak-references

To avoid a memory leak I wrote the following method that will be used in activities and mainly in fragments (using inheritance). That method is supposed to allow me to never directly refer to the activity by calling

```
//this or getActivity()
```

The method is:

```
private WeakReference<BaseActivity> activityWeakReference = null; 

public BaseActivity getActivityFromWeakReference(){
        activityWeakReference = activityWeakReference == null ?
                new WeakReference<BaseActivity>((BaseActivity)getActivity()) :
                activityWeakReference;
        return activityWeakReference.get();
    }
```

Is calling this method `getActivityFromWeakReference()` instead of `getActivity()` safe according to memory leak threat?

If it is not safe to do so, should I return the `activityWeakReference` and call its `get()` method instead, to make it safe?

I have been using it in multiple fragments and I haven't had any problem so far. I ask the question because I read this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326285/3808178)):

> As long as the lifetime of the helper is within the lifetime of the
>   `Activity`, then there's no need to use a `WeakReference`. If the helper
>   can live longer than the `Activity`, then you should use a `WeakReference`
>   to avoid retaining the `Activity` in your object graph when the system
>   destroys it.

So far, I haven't faced a case where a referred element outlived the activity. Please guys if you find an error or a possible one just write it in the comments.

Comment: Note that your method may return null, when `activityWeakReference` is not null, but `activityWeakReference.get()` is.

Comment: @Mateus Gondim, thanks for the input, I already check the null before using it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is totally feasible. For example you have this pseudocode code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         new DownloadTask().execute();
    }

    public void showInfo() {
    }

    class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void data) {
            // we can call showInfo() activity because Asynctask hold an implicit reference to activity 
            showInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

On above code, there is a situation will caused memory leak.

Here is the explanation:

When you create `DownloadTask` as above example, java call `DownloadTask` is an [inner class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_innerclasses.htm). An inner class will **implicit** holds a reference to outer class, in this case is `MainActivity`. Moreover, when you start an asynctask, that asynctask will be held by system until it finish. For example, you download takes 30 seconds. In that 30 seconds, you rotate your device. When you rotate your device, `MainActivity` is [re-created](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) and often old activity will be destroyed. But in this case old activity isn't destroyed because the old `MainActivity` instance is held by `DownloadTask` and `DownloadTask` is hold by system. You will leak one activity instance.

For fixing this, you should change above code to:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadTask(this).execute();
    }

    public void showInfo() {
    }
}

class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakReference;

    public DownloadTask(MainActivity activity) {
        mainActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void data) {
        if (mainActivityWeakReference.get() != null) {
            mainActivityWeakReference.get().showInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, when new `MainActivity` is created, the old one isn't held by `DownloadTask` (due to weak reference attribute), so the old one will be destroyed by Android Garbage Collector in future. You also should to check every time you use a weak reference object, because you don't know exactly when GC will destroyed those object.

Here is my own blog about another situation of memory leak. [Memory leak when using static inner class](https://blog.androidcafe.in/android-memory-leak-part-1-context-85cebdc97ab3)

Hope this help.

Comment: Should I understand that, if you use my method above ( getActivityFromWeakReference() ) it will be ok in the case you just described.

Comment: @MaximeClaude yes basically that's true. you keep WeakReference of your activity at "some place", and you should get it as your method (because in some case, it will be null because GC has cleaned it up). "Some place" depends on many situations, my example is just one.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll take a look at your blog.

Answer (score 1):

There are some case, if your fragment is set to retain instance, it'll be longer than activity, or if your fragment is leaked.