# Is a Thread with an static WeakReference able to be garbage collected or does it force MemoryLeak?

Tags: android, static, weak-references

I was asking myself, if this way:

```java
public class thread_FrequentSendingThread extends Thread {

    private static WeakReference<thread_FrequentSendingThread> myThread;

public thread_FrequentSendingThread() {
    myThread = new WeakReference<>(this);
}

public static WeakReference<thread_FrequentSendingThread> getMyThread() {
    return myThread;
}
}
```

of using a static WeakReference will cause MemoryLeak.
When is this Thread ready for being garbage collected?

What about Activites with a static WeakReference can they be garbage collected?

Is there a way to make these things ready for being garbage collected?

As this question is all about, when ever I use this WeakReference to get a Strong reference in a specified method or class, can they be garbage collected to?

Comment: See this answer on [Activities and Weak reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467584/8043806)

Comment: This is not a static reference, I know that using in inner class without static is being garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume the thread isn't running (if the thread is running, its a garbage collection root and cannot be freed).  In that case it could be garbage collected. The rules for garbage collection is that it can be collected if there are no path of strong references to it from any GC root.  A GC root is a thread, a static, a local variable (any local variable in any frame of any thread), or a JNI reference.

Whether its a good idea is another issue.  FOr Activities its a horrible idea-  there is no promise that you only have one instance of an activity at a time, so trying to use an static weak reference to the current activity (its usual use) will be broken and will cause problems when it refers to the wrong instance.

For a thread its less problematic, but still likely not the correct solution.  Especially given that finished threads can't be restarted.  I highly question if this is the best way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: 1. You say a strong reference is a static, isn't it a strong reference in this case?
2. Why can I have once or more Activites on a time? When I start an activity one, and never do this again is it possible that I have more than instance of an activity?

In my case I never restart a thread, when it is finished, and I create a new one if necessary.

I have a big project with many single threads looking for some results, My problem is that sometimes the root between 2 threads are really big and I don't know how tho send messages between them or even use methods.

Comment: 1) Strong and static are different things.  A static reference is a GC root, but the GC is the weak reference object itself, NOT the object it refers to.  THe object it refers through does not have a strong reference through that static, so it isn't ineligible for gc from that

Comment: 2) Yes.  Yes it is.  For example, if you rotate the phone the old activity will be finished and a new one created.  For a brief time 2 versions will exist.  If the user goes to open the app from the app list again a 2nd can exist.  It is NEVER safe to assume that an Activity is a singleton in android.

Comment: The answer of 1 is fascinating thx!
My device can't rotate. The app is Running or finished.

Comment: sorry I don't know where else to ask, but what do you think about this solution?
 `for (Thread thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {

            if (thread.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("t1")){
                t1A =thread;
            }else if (thread.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("t2")){
                t2A =thread;
            }
        }`

Just for threads, because I don't know how to use this with Activities.